# Python ability to manage 2 or more physical buttons

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, camera, gpio

I am making a camera. I am using a RPi 3 and python. I am using 2 GPIO attached to momentary switches. With the first button I want to be able to take pictures. The second one runs a script to shutdown the system, but IT IS NOT WORKING. This is the code. Please help.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from gpiozero import Button
import time
import os
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

button1 = Button(17)
button2 = Button(18)
camera = PiCamera()

channel = 1

if GPIO.input(18):
      button2.wait_for_press()
      print("Here I will run the shutdown code")

if GPIO.input(17):
  frame = 1
  while True:
    try:
     button1.wait_for_press()
     camera.capture('/home/pi/Vinpics/frame%03d.jpg' % frame)
     frame += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print("Just a place holder")
```

Comment: why dont you run two script separately for two different buttons???

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am new at the RPi scene and programming. Therefore, I didn't know how to do that. However, I fixed the issue.    :)